# Spark job using HBase fails

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, cloudera

Any Spark job I run that involves HBase access results in the errors below. My own jobs are in Scala, but supplied python examples end the same. The cluster is Cloudera, running CDH 5.4.4. The same jobs run fine on a different cluster with CDH 5.3.1.

Any help is greatly apreciated!

```
...
15/08/15 21:46:30 WARN TableInputFormatBase: initializeTable called multiple times. Overwriting connection and table reference; TableInputFormatBase will not close these old references when done.
...
15/08/15 21:46:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, some.server.name): java.io.IOException: Cannot create a record reader because of a previous error. Please look at the previous logs lines from the task's full log for more details.
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.createRecordReader(TableInputFormatBase.java:163)
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The input format instance has not been properly initialized. Ensure you call initializeTable either in your constructor or initialize method
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.getTable(TableInputFormatBase.java:389)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.createRecordReader(TableInputFormatBase.java:158)
... 14 more
```

Answer (score 2):

run spark-shell with this parameters:
--driver-class-path .../cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar --driver-java-options "-Dspark.executor.extraClassPath=.../cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar"

Why it works is described [here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/ClassNotFoundException-org-apache-htrace-Trace-exception-in/td-p/29200).